# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForReleases' > java.io.IOException:Please correct the above warnings first

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

when i tried to Generate Apk in android studio 2.2 and completing the Dialog appeared about this proccess, i faced with this message and building Aborted :
Please help me to sort out this...

Message :

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease,
:blurringview:assembleRelease, :core:assembleRelease,
:customlibrary:assembleRelease]
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.1_r1 for debug
Warning:Ignoring Android API artifact com.google.android:android:2.1_r1 for release
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpConnection
Warning:library class com.android.internal.http.multipart.MultipartEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning:org.acra.ErrorReporter: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme: can't find referenced method 'Base64(int)' in program class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced method 'Base64(int)' in program class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid
Warning:org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:there were 38 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 33 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "me.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 18
    versionName "1.14"
    multiDexEnabled true
    renderscriptTargetApi 21
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        jniDebuggable true
        renderscriptDebuggable true
        pseudoLocalesEnabled true
    }
}

sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = [] // disable automatic ndk-build path
    jniLibs.srcDir 'libs' // use the jni .so compiled from the manual ndk-build command
       }
    }
     android {
      lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
       }
    }

    repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/libaudiolocalizationapi.jar')
    compile project(':customlibrary')
    compile project(':core')
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.github.frank-zhu:pullzoomview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3'
    compile 'net.qiujuer.genius:blur:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.Todd-Davies:ProgressWheel:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.+'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.lukekorth:mailable_log:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    compile 'at.aau.itec.android.mediaplayer:mediaplayer:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile project(':blurringview')
    }
```

proguard-rules.txt :

```
    -dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
    -dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
    -dontnote org.apache.http.**
    -dontwarn java.awt.**
    -dontwarn org.postgresql.**
    -dontwarn com.google.**
    -dontwarn com.braintreepayments.**
    -dontwarn ch.qos.**
    -dontwarn retrofit.**
    -dontwarn ch.qos.**
    -dontwarn dagger.**
    -dontwarn com.flurry.**
    -dontwarn com.squareup.**
    -dontwarn okio.**
```

after a lot of searching, i understood that i should use -dontwarn com.whatever.library.* but nothing happend! and i still have problem

please help me sort out of this problem, thanks.

Comment: As far as I see you are not referencing your proguard-rules.txt. Try to add it to the proguardFiles tag at your build.gradle

Comment: @DevrimTuncer Actually proguard-files.text I have mentioned is my proguard-rules.pro files which i have referenced in my build.gradle